# Weird dependency convergence error

Tags: java, maven, dependencies

Here's error I see in maven build command. The weird thing I found is that the version of zeppelin-interpreter is 0.8.0-20170724.234851-5, but not 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT. In the last commit I do specify guava version as 15.0, and I updated it to 18.0 in the new commit. But I don't understand why zeppelin-zengine still depends on the old version 0.8.0-20170724.234851-5 instead of 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT. Anyone can help on that ? Thanks

```
Dependency convergence error for com.google.guava:guava:15.0 paths to dependency are:
    +-org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-zengine:0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
      +-org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-interpreter:0.8.0-20170724.234851-5
        +-com.google.guava:guava:15.0
    and
    +-org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-zengine:0.8.0-SNAPSHOT
      +-com.google.guava:guava:18.0
```

Comment: Hi have you solve this..?

Answer (score 0):

> But I don't understand why zeppelin-zengine still depends on the old
>   version 0.8.0-20170724.234851-5 instead of 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT.

You use a snapshot version of a third-party library : `org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-zengine`.
The consistency of it with these own dependencies may be inaccurate as it is a working in progress version.

It seems be the case for `org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-zengine:0.8.0-SNAPSHOT` that depends on `org.apache.zeppelin:zeppelin-interpreter:0.8.0-20170724.234851-5` and finally these two artifacts pull different versions of `com.google.guava:guava` (one pulls the `15.0` and the other the `18.0`).

I may provide you a quick and dirty way to exclude the dependency but it is really not the way to follow.
Instead, I strongly encourage you to use a released version of `zeppelin-zengine`.

For example, the `0.7.2` version released on Jun 09, 2017:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.zeppelin/zeppelin-zengine -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.apache.zeppelin</groupId>
    <artifactId>zeppelin-zengine</artifactId>
    <version>0.7.2</version>
</dependency>
```

Comment: I work on zeppelin project itself, and specify the version of zeppelin-interpreter as ${project.version}, I think ${project.version} should be 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT, right ?

Comment: Ah ok sorry. No as the inaccurate version comes from `zeppelin-zengine`. It is this artifact that pulls the time-stamped version and so that is this artifact that should be modified.

Comment: I tried both ${project.version} and 0.8.0-SNAPSHOT, but none works, very weird.

Comment: Have you reinstalled (mvn install) the zeppelin-zengine dep ? Without seeing the poms, hard to guess why.